# Can some combinations of DNS-entries be security vulnerabilities?

Tags: dns

Lets assume you have these DNS-entries for **`domain.tld`**:

```
host = domain.tld  
type = SOA  
mname = dns.otherdomain.tld  
rname = hostmaster.otherdomain.tld  

host = domain.tld  
type = NS
target = ns1.thirddomain.tld

host = domain.tld  
type = NS
target = ns2.thirddomain.tld
```

Note: For `domain.tld` there is no A-record, no AAAA-record and no CNAME-record, only the three records shown above.

This one is for **`www.domain.tld`**:

```
host = www.domain.tld  
type = CNAME
target = site.otherdomain.tld
```

And there also is this one for **`site.otherdomain.tld`**:

```
host = site.otherdomain.tld  
type = A
ip = 192.168.123.234
```

Is it possible, that this combination is vulnerable? I ask, because there are browsers (like firefox) that behave different than other browsers:

When you use Google Chrome to call http://domain.tld/ you get a message that says, that the browser can't open this site.

But when you open the same URL in Firefox, the content of `192.168.123.234` will be displayed. This is because Firefox tries to open http://www.domain.tld/ when it fails to open http://domain.tld/

Is this combination of DNS-entries safe?

btw: I found such a constellation in the wild. I have no idea, why it was made this way. I just wonder if such a constellation can rise any security risks.